# Getting a single set of elements using loops

Tags: arrays, list, append

Whenever I append an element into a new list in a loop, i get a number of lists that repeats the elements. How do i get a single list with all elements without repeating them?

```
n, r = [5, 2]
ans = 0
l = [0]
while n-1>0:
    ans = ans+r
    for i in range(ans):

        if ans not in l:
            l.append(ans)
        print(l)
    n-=1



#I was hoping to get this answer:
 [0,2,4,6,8]
#Instead, I got this:
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2]
 [0, 2, 4]
 [0, 2, 4]
 [0, 2, 4]
 [0, 2, 4]
 [0, 2, 4, 6]
 [0, 2, 4, 6]
 [0, 2, 4, 6]
 [0, 2, 4, 6]
 [0, 2, 4, 6]
 [0, 2, 4, 6]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `print` outside of `loop`:

```
n, r = [5, 2]
ans = 0
l = [0]
while n-1>0:
    ans = ans+r
    for i in range(ans):

        if ans not in l:
            l.append(ans)
    n-=1
print l
```